# Add a field into a shortcode of an extension

Tags: functions, templates

I'm very nooby to WordPress dev so I'll try to explain all the details I want, don't know if it is possible!

I'm using an extension called wp-crowfunding, in it, you can add a project from the backend or from a shortcode. In my case, I'm using et shortcode. So in it, I have a lot of fields like "title", "description" etc... but I want to add more fields.

My issue is that I can't override the original template (called: /shortcode/submit-form.php) by copying the file in my theme (not working). So I asked myself if I could use my function.php to modify this file without destroying the extension. If this is possible, I don't know how to do that.

To be more precise I need to add a WYSIWYG field in that shortcode.
If you need more information :)

Thanks in advance!

**Edit : 
Ok so now i can display my form field in the shortcode, thanks to mmm :), Now i need to display the value of it in my post.
Here the code who add my form field :**

```
add_action("plugins_loaded", function () {

    if (!isset($GLOBALS["shortcode_tags"]["wpneo_crowdfunding_form"])) {
        return;
    }

    $original_callback = $GLOBALS["shortcode_tags"]["wpneo_crowdfunding_form"];


    add_shortcode("wpneo_crowdfunding_form", function ($attr, $content, $tag) use ($original_callback) {

            $original_result = $original_callback($attr, $content, $tag);

            // customise the HTML result of the form

            $str_to_search = "<div class=\"wpneo-single\"><div class=\"wpneo-name\">Short Description";

            $str_to_insert = '<div class="wpneo-single">';
            $str_to_insert .= '<div class="wpneo-name">'.__( "Describe the team" , "wp-crowdfunding" ).'</div>';
            $str_to_insert .= '<div class="wpneo-fields">';
            ob_start();
            wp_editor( $short_description, 'wpneo-form-team-description', array('editor_height'=>200) );
            $str_to_insert .= ob_get_clean();
            $str_to_insert .= '<small>'.__("Put Here Team Description","wp-crowdfunding").'</small>';
            $str_to_insert .= '</div>';
            $str_to_insert .= '</div>';

            if (strpos($original_result, $str_to_search) !== false) {
                $posToBegin = strpos($original_result, $str_to_search);
                $original_result = substr_replace($original_result, $str_to_insert, $posToBegin, 0);
            }

            return $original_result;

        }
    );


});
```

**And here the code where i want to display it :**

```
add_filter('wpneo_crowdfunding_default_single_campaign_tabs', 'add_tab_crowdfunding_team', 20);
function add_tab_crowdfunding_team($arr){
    $arr['test_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'The Team', 'wp-crowdfunding' ),
        'priority'  => 10,
        'callback'  => 'team_tab_view_callback'
    );
    return $arr;
}

function team_tab_view_callback(){
?>
<h1>HERE THE CONTENT I WANT TO DISPLAY</h1>
<?php
}
```

Comment: which shortcode do you want to customise ? https://www.themeum.com/docs/wp-crowdfunding-shortcodes/

Comment: This one : Crowdfunding project submission form =  [wpneo_crowdfunding_form]

Comment: there is just one filter `wpneo_before_closing_crowdfunding_campaign_form` to add content at end. to modify something somewhere else, it's a little bit more complicated. in all cases, it's not recommended to put the custom code in the theme because you modify a plugin. it's better to put this code in a new plugin : https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/

Comment: A new plugin ouch ! Ok I'll try that, thanks you :)

Comment: Ok so now i created a new plugin and activated it. In it i typed that for now : `add_filter('wpneo_before_closing_crowdfunding_campaign_form', 'add_fields', 20);

function add_fields(){
    
}` now do you know how to put my html to the form ? Is there a specific way ? an array or something like that ?

Comment: you can see how to use filters here : https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/filters/

Comment: Sry but i need a bit more help, i already read this part of the documentation, but i don't understand how to do what i want. returning html code don't do anything. Again sry to bother you but i'm very nooby.

Answer (score 1):

to customise the complete result of the shortcode, you can try this code which redefine the shortcode :

```
add_action("plugins_loaded", function () {

    if (!isset($GLOBALS["shortcode_tags"]["wpneo_crowdfunding_form"])) {
        return;
    }

    $original_callback = $GLOBALS["shortcode_tags"]["wpneo_crowdfunding_form"];


    add_shortcode(
          "wpneo_crowdfunding_form"
        , function ($attr, $content, $tag) use ($original_callback) {

            $original_result = $original_callback($attr, $content, $tag);

            // customise the HTML result of the form
            $original_result = str_replace(
                  "Title"
                , "A <sup>little</sup> <sub>fantasy</sub>"
                , $original_result
            );


            return $original_result;

        }
    );


});
```

Comment: Yeaah that works :) thank you ! So now I suppose I have to register it in my database when the user click on the  submit button, then I'll need to place it in my article content ? Or does it register automatically ?

Comment: hi @mmm sorry to bother you again but i'm very lost, and no one seems to wanna help on this thread !